# The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am getting the above error in a C# program.
Below the stack trace - answers referring to this error didn't help. I try to connect to the Exchange with an email address and password. The credentials are OK.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I call `exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl( 'valid-email-address' );` - This code worked for 7 years and now it stopped working. Of course, the email address is still available on the SBS 2010.

The source contains sensitive data. The email address still does exist, the password didn't change - otherwise another exception would have been thrown. Windows throws an exception which is saying exactly nothing.
Answers regarding this error are about cleaning a cache but those directories don't exist on the server.

---

@https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/617242/autodiscover-not-working-after-exchange-server-201.html

I could only try the first option and it didn't help even no error message appeared in the console.

---

```
Error:The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator..ctor(SearchResultCollection results, String parentUserName, String parentPassword, AuthenticationTypes parentAuthenticationType)
   at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.DirectoryHelper.GetScpUrlList(String domainName, String ldapPath, Int32& maxHops)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.DirectoryHelper.GetAutodiscoverScpUrlsForDomain(String domainName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.DefaultGetScpUrlsForDomain(String domainName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetAutodiscoverServiceUrls(String domainName, Int32& scpHostCount)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetAutodiscoverServiceHosts(String domainName, Int32& scpHostCount)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetSettings[TGetSettingsResponseCollection,TSettingName](List`1 identities, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, GetSettingsMethod`2 getSettingsMethod, Func`1 getDomainMethod)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetSoapUserSettings(String smtpAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress)
```

Comment: What code have you used for that? The error message states that you have passed a wrong parameter. What line of code exactly gives the error?

Comment: I see the stack trace, but I can't find the source code.

Comment: See [Autodiscover not working after exchange server 2019 cumulative update 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/617242/autodiscover-not-working-after-exchange-server-201.html)